# Scrapy: Login to page pre-crawling

Tags: scrapy

I'm learning to build a scraper that scrapes search results but previously needs to log in. I read the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login) and this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/scrapy-this-is-how-to-successfully-login-with-ease-ea980e2c5901) here. Unfortunately, I'm still stuck. My spider reports the following `<403 https://github.com/login>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed`.

```
class GitHubSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "github"
    start_urls = [
        "https://github.com/search?p=1&q=React+Django&type=Users",
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(restrict_css="a.mr-1"),
            callback="parse_engineer",
        ),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=".next_page")),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        return [
            scrapy.FormRequest(
                url="https://github.com/login",
                formdata={
                    "login": "scrapy",
                    "password": "12345",
                },
                callback=self.parse,
            )
        ]

    def parse_engineer(self, response):
        yield {
            "username": response.css(".vcard-username::text").get().strip(),
        }
```

Edit: Answering on @SuperUser's suggestion.

```
headers = {
    [...]
}

def start_requests(self):
    # Do I have access on response here?
    token = response.xpath('//form/input[@name="authenticity_token"]/@value').get()

    return [
        scrapy.FormRequest(
            url="https://github.com/login",
            formdata={
                "login": "scrapy",
                "password": "12345",
                "authenticity_token": token,  # <-------------
            },
            headers=self.headers,
            callback=self.parse,
        )
    ]
```

Comment: It might simply be the server telling you to not scrape the page. If you can call the apge with those parameters from the browser, and this code doesn't work, the server simply has anti scripting protection. Use an API instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to settings.py and set 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False'
2. Replace the default user_agent with [another one](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/)
3. Add the [request headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58178400) from the requested page, you can get it with your browser's devtools.

Just know that they can block your IP, and also block your account.

I suggest you to use [PyGithub](https://pypi.org/project/PyGithub/) instead.

**Edit:**

The request headers:

```
class GitHubSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "github"
    start_urls = [
        "https://github.com/search?p=1&q=React+Django&type=Users",
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(restrict_css="a.mr-1"),
            callback="parse_engineer",
        ),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=".next_page")),
    )
    headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "github.com",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        "TE": "trailers",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36",
    }
    def start_requests(self):
        return [
            scrapy.FormRequest(
                url="https://github.com/login",
                formdata={
                    "login": "scrapy",
                    "password": "12345",
                },
                headers=self.headers,
                callback=self.parse,
            )
        ]

    def parse_engineer(self, response):
        yield {
            "username": response.css(".vcard-username::text").get().strip(),
        }
```

Also notice that you need to get the csrf token:

```
token = response.xpath('//form/input[@name="authenticity_token"]/@value').get()
```

Pass the token with the username and password.

```
formdata={
"login":...,
"password":...,
"authenticity_token": token,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

1. & 2. I did. For 3. I am currently struggling to figure out what's the right header. I tried it and found that one: https://ibb.co/Bwy1qTH (?) But I still don't understand how to apply it / move it to my script.

Comment: Hi @SuperUser I just posted a new question where I tried to implement your suggestions partly. Still doesn't work. :/ If you have any more input, appreciate your help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68783440/scrapy-login-crawl-doesnt-work-as-expected