# Scrapy: Login > Crawl doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to learn to log in to my spider. For that, I created the attached code. The expected outcome is:

```
{
   "username": "willingc",
   "email": "carolcode@willingconsulting.com",
   "url": "https://www.willingconsulting.com",
}
```

However, the actual outcome is:

```
{
   "username": "willingc",
   "email": None,
   "url": "https://www.willingconsulting.com",
}
```

`None` usually occurs if the browser isn't logged in. Do you see any errors in my code? The only indicator I see that something is wrong, is the following WARNING:

> WARNING:py.warnings:/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py:287:
> RuntimeWarning: Could not load referrer policy
> 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin'

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest


class GitHubSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "github"
    allowed_domains = ["github.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://github.com/login"]

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//form/input[@name="authenticity_token"]/@value').get()
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                "authenticity_token": token,
                "login": "mygithub@gmail.com",
                "password": "12345",
            },
            callback=self.parse_after_login,
        )

    def parse_after_login(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://github.com/willingc",
            callback=self.parse_engineer,
        )

    def parse_engineer(self, response):

        yield {
            "username": response.css(".vcard-username::text").get().strip(),
            "email": response.xpath('//li[@itemprop="email"]/a//text()').get(),
            "url": response.xpath('//li[@itemprop="url"]/a//@href').get(),
        }
```

Comment: I used your code and got {'username': 'willingc', 'email': 'carolcode@willingconsulting.com', 'url': 'https://www.willingconsulting.com'}

Comment: Oh wow, you are actually right. That's very interesting. I used gitpod.io, but now tested it locally instead where I see the desired result. Wonder why...